# Execute commands in ZooKeeper Command Line Interface using Python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, subprocess, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-manager

Am trying Cloudera Manager APIs with the help of Python in AWS. I was trying to execute some commands in the Zookeeper Command Line Interface after executing the script 'zkCli.sh'.
I have tried using the below command using subprocess and am able to login to the zookeeper cli.

> subprocess.call('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t -t -i
>   /home/ec2-user/key.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx "sudo
>   /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkCli.sh"', shell=True)

Can anybody help me to execute other commands in the zookeeper cli (say 'ls /') using the same subprocess.

Is there any other methods to achieve the above case in Python ?

Comment: does it have to be python?

Comment: @MichelleTan  I was trying with the _cloudera manager api_ in python. If there is no other options in python, am ready to try any other options. The whole intention is to automate command execution in zookeeper cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the cloudera API. You can maybe use Python to execute a script.
Have you tried Heredoc? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document 
You could run it on the terminal or put in in a shell script to execute it automatically.It would be something like this:

`bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 << END
create /zookeeper/Testing "Testdata"
quit
END`

or even output into a log file

`bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181 >> zkAutomation.log << END
create /zookeeper/Testing "Testdata"
quit
END`

Comment: Thanks @Michelle Tan for the response. I have tried out this and am able to execute my commands in the zookeeper cli. I have created a shell script and I executed that script from the Python and there by am able to automate my job with the same Python script.. :)